# Docker-compose volumes not mounted correctly in VirtualBox under Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, hyperledger

I am trying to run Hyperledger's [BYFN Tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) on a Win10 Home using Docker Toolbox, with VirtualBox 5.2.4. I am using the default image for the VirtualBox VM.

I have set up a shared folder (not in C:/Users, but on my other drive) and it seems to be functioning correctly - changes I make from either Windows, or the docker-machine are reflected in both places as intended. I successfully generate the network artifacts using "./byfn -m generate", but I get an error when trying to "./byfn up" it.

What happens is that, as far as I can see from the logs, all the containers get brought up correctly, but for some reason the volumes of the `cli` container are not attached correctly (I think). When byfn.sh finishes I get the following error:

[image]

When I ssh into the `cli` container, I can see the `channel-artifacts`, `crypto` and `scripts` folders, but their contents don't seem to correlate with the `volumes:` part of the docker-compose file. First, the scripts folder is empty (whereas in the docker-compose file it's specified that it should mount a bunch of files), so I get the above error. Second, the `channel-artifacts` containes only 1 **directory** named `genesis.block`, which should actually be a **file**. And in the `crypto` folder there are just a bunch of directories.

As you might have guessed, I'm pretty new at docker, so this might be intended behavior, but I'm still getting an error.

Please let me know if I can provide additional information. Thanks in advance.